# Does Kile support Column/Block Selection?

Tags: kile

Is it possible to select a rectangular area in a file with Kile, using the mouse or the keyboard? If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Edit --> Block Selection Mode, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>. This switches the mode on/off. When it is on, selection with mouse/keyboard is block selection.

Comment: Unfortunately editing of all the selected lines at the same time does not work.

Comment: @sergej Copying, pasting and deleting all work, so some editing is possible. Typing, as in Notepad++, is not though, it seems.